# PySpark is raising error (ORA-00933) when fetching data from Oracle Database

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

### Context

I am using Databricks to connect to an Oracle Database and fetch data daily. We are using the following example code in PySpark to authenticate and access the database:

```
testDF = (spark.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.80.40.5:1526:D301")
    .option("dbtable", "SCHEMA_TEST.TABLE_TEST")
    .option("user", jdbcUsername)
    .option("password", jdbcPassword)
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    .option("oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion", "false")
    .option("fetchSize", "256")
    .load()
    .createOrReplaceTempView("test")
)
```

Then we used to access the information via SQL code using the command below:

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

### The problem

Today we realized this approach is raising an error like the one below:

> SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> Caused by: OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00933: SQL command not
> properly ended

Upon further investigation into the error log, I saw the following message:

> Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 2735, Sql = SELECT *
> SCHEMA_TEST.TABLE_TEST LIMIT 10 , Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command
> not properly ended

So I believe that PySpark/DBSQL translates the instruction `SELECT * FROM test` into the instruction `SELECT * SCHEMA_TEST.TABLE_TEST LIMIT 10` to fetch information from the Oracle database.

The problem is that LIMIT does not exist in the ORACLE SQL Clause, therefore raising the error.

So I tried to implement an instruction with a WHERE clause. Because I thought that the translation would prevent to use of the LIMIT clause in the backend. The following code then was executed:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE column_example is not null
```

Well, IT WORKED. So for some reason, the PySpark/DBSQL is translating a simple select star instruction (`SELECT * FROM test`) WRONGLY.

Does someone know what might be the reason behind it?

### Additional info:

Databricks Runtime: 12.0
Spark: 3.3.1
Oracle Driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Maven Oracle Driver: com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  I changed my databricks runtime to 10.4 LTS and it resolved the issue.

Comment: I have a similar problem with runtime 11.3 LTS. I can see the limit clause added for group by queries as well. Yet to try out with an older runtime. Is there a bugs tracker for Databricks where i can check if this issue has been noted and planned for a fix?

Comment: Thanks @Michael Gardner. I am able to use 10.4 LTS runtime for oracle queries. Hoping it gets fixed in next releases of Databricks.

Comment: I also was able to use the DBR 10.4 LTS to query the Oracle Database properly. Well, this can be an error in the Runtime release 12.0 or even a deprecation of the Oracle Driver (as I believe it was released a long time ago).

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternate approach by closing query in parentheses and passing query instead of calling entire table.

```py
   queryString = "(SELECT * SCHEMA_TEST.TABLE_TEST LIMIT 10)"
    print("Query to fetch data from Oracle:: ", query)
    # Fetch data from query
    oracleDataDf = spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", oracleUrl)
      .option("dbtable", queryString)
      .option("user", oracleDbUser)
      .option("password", oracleDbPass)
      .option("driver", oracleDriver)
      .load()

    oracleDataDf.show()
```

Comment: Same error using the push down a query technique =/